# Strip TZSP Encapsulation - live traffic

Tags: python, logging, header, scapy

I'm creating a log server, that write incoming and outgoing connections (any type) to a TXT file . everything is working fine and here is my code :

```
from scapy.all import *
import datetime
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue, Empty
from scapy.layers.dns import DNS, DNSQR
firstime = 0
times = time.time()+86400
def print_summary(pkt):
    global firstime
    global times
    if IP in pkt:
        ip_src=pkt[IP].src
        ip_dst=pkt[IP].dst
    else:
        ip_src="Null"
        ip_dst="Null"
        mac_src="Null"
        mac_dst="Null"    
    if TCP in pkt:
        tcp_sport=pkt[TCP].sport
        tcp_dport=pkt[TCP].dport
    else:
        tcp_sport="Null"
        tcp_dport="Null"
    if DNSQR in pkt:
        dns = pkt.qd.qname
    else:
        dns = "NULL"
    if Ether in pkt:
        mac_src = pkt[Ether].src
        mac_dst = pkt[Ether].dst
    else:
        mac_src = "Null"
        mac_dst = "Null"  
    Clog = " IP src: " + str(ip_src) +" ,MAC src: " + str(mac_src) + " , IP dst: " + str(ip_dst) +" ,MAC dst: "+str(mac_dst)+" ,TCP sport: " + str(tcp_sport) + ",TCP dport: " + str(tcp_dport) +", Time: " + str(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(pkt.time))) + " Dns: "+dns
    if(times > pkt.time):
        if(firstime == 0):
            f = open("/root/Desktop/LOG-SERVER/"+time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:', time.localtime(time.time()))+".txt",'a')
            f.write(Clog+"\n")
            f.close()       
        else:
            f.write(Clog+"\n")
            f.close()   
    else:
        f = open("/root/Desktop/LOG-SERVER/"+time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:', time.localtime(time.time()))+".txt",'a')
        f.write(Clog+"\n")
        f.close()       
        times=times+86400
def startsnif():
    sniff(prn=print_summary, store=0)
    # you can filter with something like that
    #if ( ( pkt[IP].src == "192.168.0.1") or ( pkt[IP].dst == "192.168.0.1") ):
     #   print("!")
#def writing(log,indexp):
    #if(indexp == 0):
        #f = open("/root/Desktop/LOG-SERVER/"+time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:', time.localtime(time.time()))+".txt",'a')
        #f.write(log+"\n")
        #f.close()
    #else:
        #f.write(log+"\n")
        #f.close()

thread.start_new_thread(startsnif,());
while 1:
        pass
# or it possible to filter with filter parameter...!
#sniff(filter="ip and host 192.168.0.1",prn=print_summary)
```

output is:

```
IP Src: 192.168.10.1 MAC Src: 54:55:12:FC:2D:CA IP Dst:192.168.10.15 MAC Src: 54:55:12:FC:1F:3A TCP sport: 80 TCP dport: 51233 Time:2015-12-16 13:25:11 DNS:Null(IF available DNS Name)
```

the problem is that the company got mikrotics, mikrotics mirror traffic through a technique called TZSP Sniff which encapsulate the packet with the  IP of the router and MAC of the router IP of the destination PC MAC of the destination pc, i was searching and i couldn't find any appropriate solution but i read that you need to strip first 5 bytes of a packet.

is there a way to strip the TZSP encapsulation live(without saving PCAP), could you please explain the process because I'm new to this stuff?

please if you have any question ask I'm not very good in explaining stuff.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After examining the binary of the TZSP packet header it appears that TZSP strip original mac address after adding it's own, so the project was closed thank you for the help.